# How do I undo this setting on a MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, text-input

Turns out cats' paws are not a very reliable input method. The cat walked across the keyboard, and now I am stuck in a "secure text field". It looks like this:

[image: ono halp]

How do I get out of here?

[question asked on [this person's behalf](https://twitter.com/khudak11/status/100366807147347968), since I couldn't find them an answer myself]

Comment: I've never seen that before. How do you even activate it?

Comment: @Kyle Dunno. Ran into somebody on the twitters whose cat made this happen. I've never seen it before, and neither had the Googles...

Comment: It must be a specific app then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've managed to enable [VoiceOver](http://www.apple.com/accessibility/voiceover/)! If your sound had been turned on, you'd also hear your computer speaking the words that appear on screen. VoiceOver is OS X's built-in screen reading software for the vision-impaired. It can speak and display lots of information about the elements on screen, including the currently-active text field.

You can disable/enable it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on newer keyboards). This and more accessibility-related settings and keyboard shortcuts can be found in the Universal Access preferences, and the Universal Access section of the Keyboard preferences.

[image]
[image]

(In Lion, it seems you get an intro dialog when enabling VoiceOver — perhaps this doesn't happen when the computer is locked, or in previous versions of OS X.)
[image]

Comment: I read a bunch of other posts that didn't help. The simple direction to hit Command F5 fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found it. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

[The by-proxy OP [found the answer on their own](https://twitter.com/khudak11/status/100370765404307456).]

Comment: Weird...didn't know there was a time limit.

Comment: For the future curious... this is VoiceOver.

Comment: @jtbandes do add more info, and I'll transfer the checkmark!